# Relational database - purchase orders

Tags: relational-database, purchase-order

I have a question regarding a relational database.

I have several purchase orders with certain budget. When this budget is spent I receive another Purchase order which is a supplement of another one.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix a relational database in excel so that I can always keep track of the budget and what has already been spent and invoiced as well as use the correct purchase order for new invoices?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What does "how to fix a relational database in excel" mean?

Comment: No "thanks" in questions.